# Django crispy forms in base.html

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms

I'm trying to set a newsletter form in the base.html. However, due to lack of personal ability and available examples, I cannot find a way to render the newsletter specific form in the base.html footer.
Currently, I have the following model form based on a application model (Newsletter) at BioPyApp/forms/newsletter.py:

```
from django import forms
from BioPyApp.models import Newsletter
from crispy_forms.bootstrap import Field
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import Submit, Layout, Fieldset, Column, Row, Div


class NewsletterForm(forms.ModelForm):

    email = forms.EmailField(required=True,label="E-mail",max_length=254)

    class Meta:
       model = Newsletter
       fields = ['email'] 

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       super(NewsletterForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
       self.helper = FormHelper()
       self.helper.form_method = 'post'
       self.helper.form_action = '/newsletter'
       self.helper.add_input(Submit('submit', 'Submit', css_class='btn-success'))
       self.helper.form_class = 'form-vertical'
       self.helper.help_text_inline = False
       self.helper.form_tag = False
       self.helper.layout = Layout(Row(Field('email')))

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        if Newsletter.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
             raise forms.ValidationError("Email already in newsletter.")
        return email
```

My view currently at BioPyApp/views.py:

```
from .forms.newsletter import NewsletterForm


    def newsletter(request):
        form = NewsletterForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return {'success': True}
```

Which I set in url as :

```
path('newsletter/',views.newsletter),
```

My questions are: is this the correct structure for a global project form? What should I write in base.html? (Note: If I put `{% crispy form %}` other forms (depending on the url) are displayed instead.)

Best regards,

Andre

Comment: You want the newsletter form on every page of your website? If that’s really what you want, it means you’d have to add it to the the context for every request. That can be done by defining your own [TemplateContextProcessor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors) and adding the form to your context. Don’t call your context variable `form` but `newsletter_form` and then you can render it in base.html with `{% crispy newsletter_form %}`

Comment: Note: I would handle form posting via ajax because if an error occurs you have no way of showing it as you do it know.